# console gives a string isn't a function error

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I'm creating a quiz and console shows a problem with split, that it's not a function, but it worked before. I've tried using toString method but it doesn't help, console says instead that can't read properties of null. If someone could help me, it would be appreciated.

```
let correctAnswer = document.getElementById("correct-answers");
    document.querySelector(".check").onclick = function () {
        /* Hide unneeded sections and showing scores */
        quiz.classList.add("hidden");
        correctAnswer.classList.remove("hidden");

        /*Showing all previous scores */
        const lastScore = localStorage.getItem("latestScore") || [];

        const scoreDetail = lastScore.split(',');

        scoreDetail.push(score);

        localStorage.setItem("latestScore", scoreDetail);

        let userScoreTemplate = `<h2>This Round's Score: ${score}</h2>`;

        scoreDetail.map((items, index) => {
            userScoreTemplate += `<h3>Score ${index}: ${items}</h3>`
        });

        let userScoreBoard = document.getElementById("user-score");

        userScoreBoard.innerHTML = userScoreTemplate;
```

Comment: Please include exact error message

Comment: _“but it worked before”_ — yeah, when the local storage entry didn’t exist yet and you got the default `[]` instead of a string.

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage.getItem()` will return a string.

You need adjust your code accordingly to default to a string in case the item is not defined:

```js
const lastScore = localStorage.getItem("latestScore") || "";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code lastScore is an array, not a string, so the split method will not work on it. It works only on strings.You can use JSON.Parse like that. This will convert array data into javascript array.

```
     const scoreDetail = JSON.parse(lastScore) || [];

scoreDetail.push(score);
```

And after that convert the array into a JSON string :

```
      localStorage.setItem("latestScore", JSON.stringify(scoreDetail));
```

Answer (score 0):

is latest score is a obj/array/string or what?
If it's an array/object then wrap `localStorage.getItem` in `JSON.parse()` so js can convert array data into js array

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, You are trying to apply split on an array instead of a string.

[image]

Looks like, `localStorage.getItem("latestScore")` is undefined while you are trying to access it and it assigned an empty array to `lastScore` variable.

Hence, Instead of

```
const lastScore = localStorage.getItem("latestScore") || [];
```

Use

```
const lastScore = localStorage.getItem("latestScore") || "";
```